# How to send a follow-up to an interviewer after a Skype interview (not given their e-mails)?

Tags: interviewing, internship

I have an upcoming Skype interview with two directors of a company. If they don't give their e-mails to you after the interview, how would you send a thank you note or follow-up? Would sending a message in linkedin be a good way? Or would you normally just e-mail the person that you have a contact with and pass the thank you to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would sending a message in linkedin be a good way?

If you do not have their direct email address, this is a perfectly acceptable way to reach out and say "*Thank you for your time.*" ( Normally a direct email would be the way to go, but we make do with what we have. )

You should also reach out to the person who set up the interview for you, if applicable.  ( Meaning this person is not part of the interview being set up )